# Why does this change the order of evaluation in F#

Tags: f#, iterator, lazy-evaluation, memoization

I am working through the Project Euler puzzles (https://projecteuler.net/) using F#. It turns out that a lot of the puzzles require the generation of prime numbers, which is an expensive computation.

To make my life easier, I want to create a module that will generate prime numbers, but also write them to a text file so I just look them up the next time I need them.

Here is my prime generator module:

```
module Utilities

open System
open System.IO
open System.Reflection

module Primes =

    //This is where the cache file is
    let private cachePath = 
        Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) 
        + "\PrimeCache.txt"

    //Parses the file to an int list
    let private readCache : int list =
        let text = File.ReadAllText(cachePath).Trim()            
        text.Split([|','|]) 
        |> Seq.filter(fun w -> w |> String.length > 0)
        |> Seq.map(fun w -> Int32.Parse(w)) 
        |> Seq.toList

    //Writes an int list to the file
    let writeCache cache =
        let text = String.Join(",", cache |> Seq.map(fun n -> n.ToString()))
        File.WriteAllText(cachePath, text)

    //In-memory cache
    let mutable cache = []
    cache <- readCache

    let private appendElement element list = 
        element::(list |> List.rev) |> List.rev

    let private isPrimeInner (n : int) =
        if n < 2 then false
        else 
            let len = cache.Length
            //Factor can't be greater than the square root
            let factorLimit = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(n))))

            let mutable i = 0
            let mutable stop = false
            let mutable isPrime = true

            while stop = false do
                //Get the next element from cache
                let p = cache.[i]

                i <- i+1

                //Don't go past last index of cache
                if i >= len
                then stop <- true 
                else ()

                //Don't check primes > sqrt(n)
                if p > factorLimit
                then stop <- true
                else ()

                //If its divisible by any prime, its not a prime
                if n % p = 0
                then 
                    stop <- true
                    isPrime <- false
                else ()

            //Add primes to cache
            if isPrime
            then cache <- appendElement n cache
            else ()

            isPrime

    let isPrime (n : int) : bool =            
        let result = isPrimeInner n
        result

    let getPrimes : int seq =
        seq {
            for p in cache do 
                yield p

            let next = if cache.Length > 0 
                       then cache.[cache.Length-1]+1
                       else 2

            for n = next to Int32.MaxValue do
                if isPrimeInner n
                then yield n
                else ()
        }

    let saveCache : unit =
        writeCache cache
```

Here is the code for the problem I am currently working on that consumes this.  (The actual problem is to sum all primes under 2,000,000, but I am testing on 1000 for now):

```
module Problem10

let getAnswer =

    let limit = 1000

    let primes = Utilities.Primes.getPrimes
                |> Seq.takeWhile(fun p -> p < limit)

    let result = primes |> Seq.sum

    Utilities.Primes.saveCache

    result
```

This will give the right answer, but will save an empty cache file back to the disk.  If I step through it in the debugger, the call to `saveCache` is one of the first things that is hit, before any breakpoints I set inside `isPrimeInner`.  If I switch the calling code to this:

```
module Problem10

let getAnswer =

    let limit = 1000

    let primes = Utilities.Primes.getPrimes
                |> Seq.takeWhile(fun p -> p < limit)

    let result = primes |> Seq.sum

    let x = Utilities.Primes.cache
    Utilities.Primes.writeCache x

    result
```

the cache will be properly saved with new primes.

I've seen this kind of behavior before in C# when misusing iterator blocks.  I don't understand how these two versions of the calling code are any different at runtime.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Utilities.Primes.saveCache` in your second snippet is not a function call. To call this function you need to add `()` like this: `Utilities.Primes.saveCache()`

Comment: If I add parenthesis I get the compiler error _This value is not a function and cannot be applied_

Comment: Ahh I see.  I needed empty parenthesis at the function declaration too

Comment: I still don't really understand why the debugger will break on `Utitilies.Primes.saveCache` before it evaluates the expressions before that though.  I thought F# used eager evaluation by default.

Comment: For .NET runtime modules in F# are just static classes and your `Utilities.Primes.saveCache` is a static field in this class. The order of initialization of static fields depends on internal F# implementation of modules

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking about this with too much C# bias.